# How to remember checked box positions?

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a listview with a custom array adapter, and I am trying to figure out how to retain the state of which positions were checked. I was thinking of saving the checkbox position to an int array each time the item is checked, and then in getView if the array contains the number it would set isChecked()==true. However, I do not really know how to search through an array. Any help would be great! here is some basic code on the adapter:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Contact c = (Contact) getItem(position);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        // if the array item is null, nothing to display, just return null
        if (c == null) {
            return null;
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
        getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        TwoLineListItem view;


        if (convertView == null) {
            view = (TwoLineListItem) inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = (TwoLineListItem) convertView;
        }

        final int pos = position;
       final SharedPreferences myprefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myprefs.edit();
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (buttonView.isChecked()){

                contactInfo.add(pos+","+c.getName()+","+c.getNumber());

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (String s : contactInfo)
                {
                    sb.append(s);
                    sb.append("\t");
                }

                editor.putString("contacts", sb.toString()).commit();



                }else {
                    contactInfo.remove(pos+","+c.getName()+","+c.getNumber());
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (String s : contactInfo)
                    {
                        sb.append(s);
                        sb.append("\t");
                    }
                    editor.putString("contacts", sb.toString()).commit();

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox check =(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.check);
            check.setTag(new Integer(childPosition));
            check.setChecked(listEditable.get(childPosition).isSelected());
            check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {          
                  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                    {
                        Integer myPosition=(Integer)buttonView.getTag();
                        if ( isChecked )
                        {
                            listEditable.get(myPosition).setSelected(true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            listEditable.get(myPosition).setSelected(false);
                        }
                    }         
            });
```